# Is it possible to publish a VS Code extension using an experimental API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using Using Proposed extension API for my extension and would like to publish it to the market place. But the unfortunately it is not allowed it seems. Is there a way to do it?

My extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bb-spectacle.bb-spectacle

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and is stated in the latest [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_33#_proposed-extension-apis) of VS Code (currently v1.33.0):

> Note that you cannot publish an extension that uses a proposed API. We may likely make breaking changes in the next release and we never want to break existing extensions.

Comment: Not sure if it is true. Github pull requests extension uses proposed API and it is published on marketplace: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/blob/master/package.json#L13